# Cannot find imported Module TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to setup  new **TypeScript** HTML project in VS 2015. I have set the typescript build settings to **commonJs**, **es5** and also had the **tsconfig.json**, which is

```
   {
 "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

Here is my main **app.ts**

```
  import t = require('./test');

class Greeter {
element: HTMLElement;
span: HTMLElement;
timerToken: number;
t: any;

constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.element = element;
    this.element.innerHTML += "The time is: ";
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    this.element.appendChild(this.span);
    this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
    this.t = new t.sample.test();
}

start() {
    this.timerToken = setInterval(() => this.span.innerHTML = new Date().toUTCString(), 500);
    this.t.hello();
}

stop() {
    clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
  }

 }

 window.onload = () => {
  var el = document.getElementById('content');
   var greeter = new Greeter(el);
   greeter.start();
};
```

Here is my imported module **test.ts**

```
   export module sample {
export class test {
    constructor() { }
    hello = () => {

        console.log("Test");
    }
  }
 }
```

Here is the html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>


    </head>
   <body>
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
   <div id="content"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

The project builds fine, but when i open that in browser chrome or IE, it throws error in console that it cannot find **test** and the file is never downloaded in to browser. Can any one suggest what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my recommended fix...

**Step One** - compile for AMD (or UMD) instead of CommonJS:

```
"module": "amd",
```

**Step Two** - ditch the internal module here:

```
  export module sample {
```

**Step Three** - Add RequireJS (Available as a NuGet package)

**Step Four** - Use Require JS

```
<script src="require.js" data-main"app"></script>
```